# jquery - not building html in ie8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to work out why this is not working in ie8. I am using jquery-2.0.2.js and cycle.js

Jquery is not my strong point, so any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#s4')
        .after('<div id="nav">')
        .cycle({
            fx: 'turnUp',
            speed: 'slow',
            pager: '#nav',
            delay: '6000',
            pause: 'true',
            pagerAnchorBuilder: function (idx, slide) {
                if (idx == 0) {
                    return '<a class="nav-border-right"><div class="circle">1</div></a>';
                }
                else if (idx == 1) {
                    return '<a class="nav-border-center"><div class="circle">2</div></a>';
                }

                else if (idx == 2) {
                    return '<a class="nav-border-center"><div class="circle">3</div></a>';
                }
                return '<a class="nav-border-left"><div class="circle">4</div></a>';
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: does it work in other browsers, FF, Chrome?

Comment: Did you read the hint at [jQuery API](http://jquery.com/download/)? "jQuery 2.x has the same API as jQuery 1.x, but does not support Internet Explorer 6, 7, or 8."

Comment: Jquery 2.0 isn't supporting IE8 : http://jquery.com/browser-support/

Comment: For one thing, I would change `.after('<div id="nav">')` to `.after($('<div />', { id: 'nav' }))`. Also 2+ doesn't support 8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> jQuery 2.x has the same API as jQuery 1.x, but does not support
>   Internet Explorer 6, 7, or 8.

From: www.jquery.com

Comment: Thanks - that was the problem

Answer (score 1):

From all i see.....it doesn't just affect IE 6, 7, 8. It also affects Firefox 3. I tested my jquery cycle plugin demo on FF3. it failed just the same way it failed on IE 6,7 and 8. Jquery announced this defect/problem before jquery 2.0.2 was released http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/

It also affects jquery ui 1.10.3. Its a change, not a bug.